# Django rest e angularjs erro cors

Tags: angularjs, python, django, cors, csrf

Estou usando django rest e angularjs 1.x em um projeto, no caso deste projeto backend e frontend estão isolados, estou usando um servidor com gulp para rodar o angularjs, porém quando tento acessar a api rest atravez do método `$http.get` do angular, o browser me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 0.0.0.0:8000/api/clients/?format=json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

sim, estou usando o Chrome, pensei que o erro estava no navegador, então parti para o Firefox, mas continuou do mesmo jeito, também tentei fazer uso do django-cors só que, infelizmente não obtive sucesso com o mesmo, procurei alguma solução tanto aqui no stack como no google em geral mas não tive um retorno favorável.

Alguém já passou por este tipo de problema? se sim como resolver este empasse?

desde já fico grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que as requisições devem ser da mesma origem quando você utiliza uma requisição `XmlHttpRequest`.

Você precisa configurar a aplicação que fornece os dados para aceitar a origem de onde você está tentando capturar a requisição (a aplicação feita em `angular`).

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Django Cors Headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) para que as requisições não tenha mais esse erro.

Relacionado:

[Qual é o significado de CORS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-de-cors/145493#145493)

Answer (score 0):

Instale o Cors no django:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Depois no settings.py coloque nos seus apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
..............
'corsheaders',
]
```

E por último ainda no settings.py :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```